# Google API calling through postman

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postman

Google API calling through postman.

Get url https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/projectid/logs/

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"id\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'id' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"id\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'id' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: not able to get data post man

Comment: I'm afraid that it's necessary to add authentication to the request, you should pass a bearer token with the get request. Also review where are you passing that id field, are you wrting your request with your project Id where the keyword "projectId" is, right?
Take a look to:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/#bearer-token